# how do i design a test class for visualforce controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, code-coverage

I am new to the Salesforce Apex development, i know the basic knowledge of test classes, but i am not able to write the Test class for the below code
please help, i somehow designed the test class with 48%, Any help would be highly appreciated so that code coverage reaches 100%

**apex class**

```
 public class ProductSearchPopupController {

    public String query {get; set;}
    public List<PricebookEntry__c> products {get; set;}
    public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList {get; set;}
    public List<PricebookEntry__c> selectedProduct{get;set;}
    public List<QuoteLineitem__c> quoteLineList{get;set;}
    public List<wrapProduct> selectedWrapperList{get;set;}
    public Boolean normalList{get;set;}
    public Boolean selectedList{get;set;}
    public Boolean block{get;set;}
    public Boolean block1{get;set;}
    public Boolean block2{get;set;}
    public String SalesPrice {get; set;}
    public integer Discount {get; set;}
    public String Quantity {get; set;}
    public String ServiceDate {get; set;}
    Id recordId;

    public ProductSearchPopupController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        recordId = controller.getId();
        system.debug('recordId '+recordId);
        wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
        selectedWrapperList = new List<wrapProduct>();
        normalList = true;
        selectedList = false;
        block = true;
        block1 = false;
        block2 = false;
    }

    public PageReference runQuery(){
        if(query == null || query == ''){
            system.debug('query '+query);
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info,'Please enter Product to search for'));

            return null;
        }
        system.debug('query '+query);
        List<List<PricebookEntry__c>> searchResults=[FIND :query IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING PricebookEntry__c (id, Name, ProductCode__c, Product2Id__r.Product_Description__c,UnitPrice__c, UseStandardPrice__c)];
        if(searchResults[0]!=null){
            for(PricebookEntry__c a: searchResults[0]) {
                // As each Account is processed we create a new wrapAccount object and add it to the wrapAccountList
                wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(a));
                block = true;
                block1 = true;
                block2 = false;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference ProceedWithSelectedToNextPage(){
        selectedWrapperList = new List<wrapProduct>();
        normalList = false;
        selectedList = true;
        for(wrapProduct selectedWrapObj: wrapProductList){
            system.debug('selectedWrapObj.selected  ---------'+selectedWrapObj.selected);
            if(selectedWrapObj.selected == true)
                selectedWrapperList.add(selectedWrapObj);
        }
        system.debug('selectedWrapperList size ---------'+selectedWrapperList.size());
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/AccountOpportunityTwoPage');
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
        return pageRef;
    }
    public void processSelected() {
        selectedProduct = new List<PricebookEntry__c>();
        for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
            if(wrapProductObj.selected == true) {
                selectedProduct.add(wrapProductObj.acc);
                block = false;
                block1 = false;
                block2 = true;

            }
        }
    }

    public class wrapProduct{
        public PricebookEntry__c acc {get;set;}
        public Boolean selected {get;set;}
        public wrapProduct(PricebookEntry__c p) {
            this.acc = p;
            this.selected = false;
        }

    }

    public pagereference saveproduct(){ 
        List<QuoteLineitem__c> quoteLineList = new  List<QuoteLineitem__c>();
        if(!selectedProduct.isEmpty()){
            for(PricebookEntry__c sp:selectedProduct){
                system.debug('sp '+sp);
                QuoteLineitem__c qli = new QuoteLineitem__c();
                qli.QuotesId__c = recordId;
                qli.ListPrice__c = sp.UnitPrice__c;
                qli.UnitPrice__c = sp.UnitPrice__c;
                qli.Product2Id__c = sp.Product2Id__c;    
                if(Discount!=0 || Discount!=null){
                    qli.Discount__c = Discount;
                }
                quoteLineList.add(qli);
            }


            if(quoteLineList.size()>0){
                insert quoteLineList;
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://proseraa.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Quotes__c/'+recordId+'/view');
                pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

**Test Class**

```
    @isTest
Private class TestProductSearchpopupController {
    @isTest
    static void testMethod1() 
    {   
        Account acc = new Account (name='Pencil');
        insert acc;
        Opportunity opp= new Opportunity ();
        opp.name= 'Testopp1';
        Opp.Accountid= acc.id;
        opp.CloseDate= date.today();
        opp.StageName= 'Qualification';
        insert opp;

        List <Quotes__c> lstquote = new List<Quotes__c>();

        Quotes__c testque = new Quotes__c();
        testque.Name = 'Test PriceBookEntry';
        testque.OpportunityId__c = opp.id;
        testque.AccountId__c = acc.id;
        lstquote.add(testque);

        List <Product2__c> lstproduct = new List<Product2__c>();
        Product2__c testProduct = new Product2__c();
        testProduct.Name='Test product';
        lstproduct.add(testProduct);

        List <PricebookEntry__c> lstpbe = new List<PricebookEntry__c>();

        PricebookEntry__c testpbe = new PricebookEntry__c();
        testpbe.Name='Test PriceBookEntry';
        lstpbe.add(testpbe);

        List <QuoteLineitem__c> lstqli = new List<QuoteLineitem__c>();
        QuoteLineitem__c testqli = new QuoteLineitem__c();
        testqli.QuotesId__c = testque.id;

        lstqli.add(testqli);


        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(lstquote[0]);
        ProductSearchPopupController psp = new ProductSearchPopupController(sc);
        psp.ProceedWithSelectedToNextPage();
        psp.processSelected();
        psp.runQuery();
        psp.saveproduct();
        Test.stopTest();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Testing a controller is, for the most part, the same as testing anything else. The unit testing questions under the [tag:canonical-qa] tag should give you some resources that will help. One thing I will note is that your focus shouldn't be so much on coverage, but rather on _assertions and testing many different scenarios_. Assertions are important, because without them your code could say that 2 + 2 = 5 and the test would still pass. Try to make each test method focus on testing one specific method. The more scenarios you test, the higher your coverage will be.

Comment: Check out the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm#!) on making test for custom controllers.